# Swap two entry in a column based on the length in a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, swap

I have a dataframe `df` with say column `a` and `b`, I want to swap values between the column if the length of a value is more than 3

Input:

```
a       b
1       23
2       44
3       43324
4       76
```

Expected Output:

```
a      b
1      23
2      44
43324  3
4      76
```

I was thinking of something like the below:

```
df <- transform(df, df$a = ifelse(length(df$b) > 3, a, b), df$a = ifelse(length(df$b) > 3, b, a))
```

But this did not work, I know I have to use something like `df[length(df$a)]` but I am not able to figure this out.

P.S: For those who are curious, the input is basically a call report, sometimes while entering data, they swap the cell number (10 digit) and the ID number (4 digits).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you could build a custom function that works for your example:

```
swap <- function(df) {

  a <- ifelse(nchar(df$b) > 3, df$b, df$a)
  b <- ifelse(nchar(df$b) > 3, df$a, df$b)
  df$a <- a
  df$b <- b

return(df)

}

#Let's test it
swap(df)
#      a  b
#1     1 23
#2     2 44
#3 43324  3
#4     4 76
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this! I really liked that you used column name instead of index, makes it easy to modify for others

Answer (score 3):

Here is a one liner

```
df[nchar(df$b)>3, c("a", "b")] <- df[nchar(df$b)>3, c("b", "a")]
> df
#      a  b
#1     1 23
#2     2 44
#3 43324  3
#4     4 76
```

Comment: Elegant solution, mtoto was a bit quicker!

Comment: @user3875610 No problem. I Just hope it helped.